# NIFI: Why is nifi auto converting numbers to scientific notation

Tags: json, csv, double, apache-nifi, transformation

When doing a conversion using the UpdateRecord processors from Json to Csv. My data (type : double) gets transformed to a scientific number.

For example 52383896.19508 becomes 5.238389619508E7.

Can you please advise me on how I can prevent this from happening? I would like the value to remain in the original format (i.e. 52383896.19508) even after the conversion from Json to Csv.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: You'll need to show the schemas you are using for the reader and writer, and a sample json input to produce the problem